# Selecting particular rows and pasting the transpose of it

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy particular rows from a sheet and paste its transpose in a different sheet.
It would be great if anyone provide me the Macro code for doing it.

Comment: Just do it in Excel using record Macro...  it will do pretty much all of the work for you.

Comment: why macro it? just copy it then select the destination rightclick and paste-transpose...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the macro recorder to get this, pretty simple:

```
Sub test()
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, destRng As Range
Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
Set rng = ws1.Range("A1:A10")
Set destRng = ws2.Range("B1:K1")

rng.Copy
destRng.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: @pnuts - updated the code, thanks for catching that.